Pandas dont drop level of multindex when getting first value
Example
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
t=pd.DataFrame({'c1': {(1, 1, 1): 1, (1, 2, 9): 2, (2, 1, 3): np.nan, (2, 1, 7): 4, (4, 2, 2): 6}, 'c2': {(1, 1, 1): 3, (1, 2, 9): 3, (2, 1, 3): 3, (2, 1, 7): 1, (4, 2, 2): 2}})
print(t["c1"].groupby(level=[0,1]).first())

output
1  1    1.0
   2    2.0
2  1    4.0
4  2    6.0
Name: c1, dtype: float64

Desired:
1  1  1    1.0
   2  9    2.0
2  1  7    4.0
4  2  2    6.0
Name: c1, dtype: float64


Answer doesn't need to be a groupby, I feel like there has to be a way to use a slice on the iloc of an index that respects nans

Use dropna + groupby.nth:
t.dropna(subset='c1').groupby(level=[0, 1])['c1'].nth(0)

Another option, modify your code to use groupby.apply and slice with .iloc[:1] or .iloc[[0]]:
(t['c1'].groupby(level=[0,1], group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[:1])
)

Or, if you want to ensure keeping the NaN if a group has one, using groupby.idxmax:
t.loc[t['c1'].notna().groupby(level=[0, 1]).idxmax(), 'c1']

Output:
1  1    1.0
   2    2.0
2  1    4.0
4  2    6.0
Name: c1, dtype: float64


Code
Using groupby with reset_index and set_index could be a way to do it (but it's not as concise).
n = t.index.nlevels # or set manually n = 3 

out = (t.reset_index(level=2)
        .groupby(level=[0, 1]).first()
        .set_index('level_2', append=True).rename_axis([None] * n)['c1']
)

out
1 1 1  1.0   
  2 9  2.0   
2 1 3  4.0   
4 2 2  6.0   


You can simply groupby the 3 levels and add dropna at the end:
print(t["c1"].groupby(level=[0,1,2]).first().dropna())

1  1  1    1.0
   2  9    2.0
2  1  7    4.0
4  2  2    6.0


This is not the same logic, it will keep duplicated values for levels 0/1 if they have a different level 2 and non-NaN values

You can use dropna + groupby + head:
t["c1"].dropna().groupby(level=[0,1]).head(1)

